# Perform Action Based on Checking Box in Adobe using Javascript

Tags: checkbox, adobe, acrobat

I'm attempting to change a textbox value whenever a user checks a checkbox in Adobe Acrobat Pro XI using Javascript, and am inexperienced in it. I am getting an error of Syntax Error: Illegal Character 7: at line 9 based on the below code:

```
//Checked
if (this.getField("myCheckBox").value != "Off") { 
this.getField("myTextBox").value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss", new  Date());

//Not Checked
} else { 
this.getField("myTextBox ").value = “”;
}
```

I have the feeling I need to change the brackets somehow, can anyone clarify?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: JavaScript!=Java

Comment: I apologize, I have updated that. Is the question beyond that way off base? I would appreciate any direction as I put together what I have from many queries and am under the impression I am close. If that is not the case please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the quotation marks in the `else` clause are not the "correct" quotation marks

```
  this.getField("myTextBox ").value = “”;  // <-- change these to ""
```

also, probably need to remove the white-space after `"myTextBox "`

try...

```
  this.getField("myTextBox").value = "";
```